# Why Struts validation not working properly?

Tags: java, struts2

I tried to validate a form in struts but whenever I used the validate method it shows "Struts has detected an unhandled exception:" which below mention

If I not validate it working very well. I enclosed the files I used.

[image]

**ACTION CLASS**

```
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

This is the action class that contains the "validate" method for validating.

public class RegistrationAction extends ActionSupport {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    Form form;

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        System.out.println(form);
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public Form getForm() {
        return form;
    }

    public void setForm(Form form) {
        this.form = form;
    }

    @Override
    public void validate() {
        if(form.getFirstname().equals(""))
            addFieldError("form.firstname", "invalid name");
    }
    

}
```

**Form.java**

```
public class Form {
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String gender;
    private String age;
    private String email;

    

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Form {firstname:'" + firstname + "', lastname:'" + lastname + "', gender:'" + gender + "', age:'" + age
                + "', email:'" + email + "}";
    }
    
    
}
```

**struts.xml**

```
<struts>

    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true"/>

    <package name="helloworld" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="index">
            <result>/index.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="hello"
            class="com.example.struct.HelloWorldAction" method="execute">
            <result name="success">/hello.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="testAction" class="com.example.struct.TestAction" method="execute">
            <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
    <package name="registration" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="reg">
            <result>/registration.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="register"
            class="com.example.registration.RegistrationAction" method="execute">
            <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

**web.xml**

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>struct_example</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <filter>
      <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
      <filter-class>
         org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
      </filter-class>
   </filter>

   <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>
   
</web-app>
```

**resgistration.jsp(registration form)**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Register here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <s:form action="register">
        <s:textfield name="form.firstname" label="First Name"></s:textfield>
        <s:textfield name="form.lastname" label="Last Name"></s:textfield>
        <s:radio name="form.gender" list="{'Male','Female'}" label="Gender" />
        <s:textfield name="form.age" label="Age"></s:textfield>
        <s:textfield name="form.email" label="Email"></s:textfield>
        <s:submit value="Register"></s:submit>
    </s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

without validate method, it working well..

Comment: Please post text, not images of text. The error summarizes nicely: there's a validation error, and no `"input"` mapping to take the client back to the form.

Comment: That's working thank you